# How to use python to press the "load more" in imdb

Tags: python, nlp, web-crawler, python-requests

I am creating a web crawler now and I want to scrape the user reviews from imdb. It's easy to directly get the 10 reviews and rate from the origin page.
For example http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1392170/reviews
The problem is to get all reviews, I need to press the "load more" so that more reviews will be shown while the url address doesn't change!
So I don't know how can I get all the reviews in Python3. What I use now are requests, bs4.

My code now:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url_link='http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/reviews?ref_=tt_urv'
html=urlopen(url_link)

content_bs=BeautifulSoup(html)

for b in content_bs.find_all('div',class_='text'):
print(b)

for rate_score in content_bs.find_all('span',class_='rating-other-user-rating'):
print(rate_score)
```

Comment: Sorry if this sounds harsh, but this is not really python related. Also if you want people to help you be sure to attach a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have updated my codes now. I just want to get an idea to get my web crawler better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By capturing network events, I have come to this conclusion. The button is defined as this in the webpage:

```
<div class="load-more-data" data-key="xxdr3yxoixpwgjg7c6vq44huu6hi6xe5qywg3adr43xlnl5sas6df5ed53iunemqakizscc53xq32" data-ajaxurl="/title/tt1392170/reviews/_ajax">
...
</div>
```

Notice the two things,

- data-key
- data-ajaxurl

After clicking the button, the web browser loads this URL via AJAX:

```
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1392170/reviews/_ajax?paginationKey=xxdr3yxoixpwgjg7c6vq44huu6hi6xe5qywg3adr43xlnl5sas6df5ed53iunemqakizscc53xq32
```

or

```
http://www.imdb.com/{data-ajaxurl}?paginationKey={data-key}
```

Comment: That's a good approach. I visit this url and I can get one more list of reviews but  it doesn't contains the new ajax info. So I still can not create a automatic loop to iterate all reviews.

Comment: @EricZhang It does. After following the link look at the very end of the returned HTML code, you will see this: <div class="load-more-data" data-key="qddrabrtdt6pdk7dkrtd6xlivqt7c4kvfd67wd4gfhtczc27nlnvp5mpuidei6y4mhjczpk5gyxby">

Comment: Using that just replace your "paginationKey", in a loop, then you will get the reviews.

Comment: Goddness! It works! Now I think I can loop all comments! Thank you!